# add a textbox to a column chart in report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

I am using report builder 3.0.  I created a column chart.  I want to place words(Requirements <= 700ms) on top of the chart defining a dashed line that I placed on the chart.  I added a textbox, tried to set all the right values to display it on top of the chart but it gets put below the chart.  I tried creating a list, dropping the textbox into the list, still displays the word below the chart and not on top of the chart.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am using report builder 3.0 to create a column chart

Answer (score 0):

Placing textboxes over charts can produce unpredictable behavior.

What you might be able to do is create multiple titles and manually position them using the Custom Position property.

It's a pain, but it's much more organized than trying to manually place textboxes.